# wrangling data using r

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I need your kind help tidying data using R.

My original data looks like this:

```
   > dput(mydata)
structure(list(subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("N1", "E1"), class = "factor"), item_number = c(1, 
2, 1, 7, 1, 2, 2, 10), block = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3), condition = c("L", 
"L", "EI", "I", "L", "L", "EI", "I")), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
 > mydata
  subject item_number block condition
1      N1           1     1         L
2      N1           2     1         L
3      N1           1     3        EI
4      N1           7     3         I
5      E1           1     1         L
6      E1           2     1         L
7      E1           2     3        EI
8      E1          10     3         I
```

For some programming error, I could not label conditions in block 1 correctly. So, I am trying to adjust that by renaming condition in block 1 for different subjects and for different item numbers. Ideally, any item_number in block 1 that is given the value L for condition should be renamed based on the condition label given to the same item_number in block 3. For example, for the subject N1, if the item_number 1 exists in block 3 and is given the label EI for condition, then, the condition label for item_number 1 in block 1 should be set to the same label which is 'EI'. If the item_number 2 does not exist in block 3 for subject N1, then the condition label for item number 2 in block 1 should be 'E'.

The desired output should look like this:

```
dput(mydata_cleaned)
structure(list(subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("N1", "E1"), class = "factor"), item_number = c(1, 
2, 1, 7, 1, 2, 2, 10), block = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3), condition = c("EI", 
"E", "EI", "I", "E", "EI", "EI", "I")), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
> mydata_cleaned
  subject item_number block condition
1      N1           1     1        EI
2      N1           2     1         E
3      N1           1     3        EI
4      N1           7     3         I
5      E1           1     1         E
6      E1           2     1        EI
7      E1           2     3        EI
8      E1          10     3         I
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to reshape to 'wide' format with column names created from 'block', then do the replacement on the column `1` based on values of `3` and reshape back to 'long' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydata %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = block, values_from = condition) %>% 
 mutate(`1` = case_when(`3` %in% "EI" & `1` %in% "L"  ~ `3`, 
       is.na(`3`) ~ 'E', TRUE ~ `1`)) %>%
 pivot_longer(cols = c(`1`, `3`), names_to = 'block',
          values_to = 'condition', values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#  subject item_number block condition
#  <fct>         <dbl> <chr> <chr>    
#1 N1                1 1     EI       
#2 N1                1 3     EI       
#3 N1                2 1     E        
#4 N1                7 3     I        
#5 E1                1 1     E        
#6 E1                2 1     EI       
#7 E1                2 3     EI       
#8 E1               10 3     I
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help and for the code @akrun. While the code worked very well for subject N1, unfortunately, it did not capture the right labels for subject E1. For example, item_number 2 should have been labelled as EI in block 1. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @azizitamimi your condition was that 'item_number' 2 and those where the block 3 doesn't have item_number 2

Comment: @azizitamimi What about the 'block 1' being changed to 'EI'

Comment: Hi @akrun, I am so sorry for the confusion and for failing to make my question very clear. Actually this should apply to any item number (not only item number 2). So, the idea is that any item number in block 1 should receive the same condition label that is assigned to the same item number in block 3. If the item number in block 1 does not appear in block3; then the same item number should be given the label E in condition for block1. Sorry again for the confusion.

Comment: @azizitamimi can you check the updated solution

Comment: That is brilliant, and it solved my problem very well. Thanks a lot akrun for such a smart solution and very efficient code.  It is greatly appreciated.